# Rails 4 : Issue when searching using Sunspot and Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr

I just set up Sunspot and Solr to give my Rails app a powerful search functionnality.

The install process is straight-forward and I did all the basic stuff required :

**Add Gems**

```
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_solr'
gem 'progress_bar'
```

**Run commands**

```
bundle
rails generate sunspot_rails:install
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
rake sunspot:solr:run
rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

Everything is fine on that level and my documents are created correctly.

Now for the search, it doesn't work really well. Here is what I did on my model and controller :

**Domain.rb**

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :name, stored: true
  end
end
```

**HomeController.rb**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @domains = Domain.search do
      fulltext params[:q], fields: [:name], highlight: true
      paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 12
    end
  end
end
```

My actual datas is a list of domain names (e,g, google.com, facebook.com...etc...)

- When searching for `goo`, it returns nothing.
- When searching for `google.com`, it finds `google.com`.

I realized that by surrounding the `fulltext` argument with `*` it does produce something similar to what `SELECT * FROM domains WHERE name LIKE '%:name%'` does.

```
@domains = Domain.search do
  fulltext "*#{params[:q]}*", fields: [:name], highlight: true
  paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 12
end
```

However, this does not work if I search for multiple words `great pizza` (hoping to find `great-super-giant-pizza.com` for example).

I might have miss a point on Sunspot/Solr setup.

Any idea?

**EDIT**

To clarify a bit this case, I even tried to do a simple search such as :

```
Domain.search { fulltext 'great pizza' }
```

as shown in the example. It does not work. Sunspot/Solr is actually trying to find a text matching exactly `great pizza` instead of finding text that match those 2 words

Comment: How is your `params[:q]`?

Comment: Also it is strange, to me, that your `HomeController#index` method is rendering itself. Just to make sure, try running a simpler search like this: `Order.search { fulltext 'great pizza' }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The `q` params is the text to search. When it's empty, it returns all results. I've tried to use a simple search as `Domain.search { fulltext 'great pizza' }` but it does return nothing...

Comment: I guess it is a problem with how you are configuring your search, I took look at the repo and they add more configuration options, have you read that?

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Wildcard-searching-with-ngrams

Comment: @user3023421: Thanks for the link. The problem here is that I don't want my users to have to type any uncommon wildcard or symbol. According to the doc, by default the engine is supposed to be able to find those simple search. But it does not. Using the default I can already search using wildcard and it works (e,g, `sun*`).

Comment: @Gerep : I didn't touch the configuration yet. Just using the defaults

Comment: @El-Key sorry, I meant the search configuration, yours is `fulltext "*#{params[:q]}*", fields: [:name], highlight: true
  paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 12` and the one from the repo is a bit different, with some extra options, have you checked what each of those are doing?

Comment: @Gerep: Oh ok. Yeah I did and don't see anything wrong at that level. Even a simple search `Domain.search { fulltext 'great pizza' }` does not work. Sunspot/Solr is actually trying to find something called exactly `great pizza` instead of trying to find domains matching those 2 words. I edited my question